# Access iCloud application data from linux

Tags: ios, linux, icloud

I have a web application for my own use that accesses the data from an [iPhone application](http://chronicleapp.com/) (It's a bill tracking app, and I have a little web-app that generates a simple page with graphs, and calculates the utility division for my roomates).

This iPhone application previously supported syncing data via dropbox, but with dropbox's recent drop of their v1 API, the application decided to drop dropbox all together, and currently only supports syncing via iCloud.

How can I access my iCloud data? More specifically, I need to do this from linux.

I've been experimenting with [PyiCloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud), and while I can access my iCloud "drive", the application specific data storage does not appear to be stored there. Reading about, iCloud seems to have a [quite complex](https://github.com/prabhu/iCloud#login-process) API, but how it actually works is basically undocumented, as far as I can tell.

I assume the "correct" approach is "use a mac", but I don't have any mac servers (I don't have a mac at all, at the moment, actually).

So, all that said, I've been unable to determine how to do this. Is this something I'd use CloudKit for? That seems like it's more for the developer of an app to use for their users, rather then something I (as an end-user) would use for accessing my account.

All I want is to get the blasted app data from a single application automatically.

---

I'm using python, but frankly if there's an example in *any* language, I can probably port it to my language of choice.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would move away from dropbox, which is generic solution. Don't get me wrong iCloud would work too and in some ways is easier to implement that Dropbox. Undocumented, no... there are WWDC videos on it, dozens of youtube courses, stacks of stack overflow questions and answers... etc etc.

Comment: @user3069232 - I **don't** want to move away from dropbox. If you can convince the [people who developed the app I'm trying to interact with that it was a terrible idea](http://chronicleapp.com/what-happened-to-dropbox-sync/), I'd be totally grateful. As it is, I'm stuck.

Comment: @user3069232 - As for the claims about documentation, if you are confident there is so much documentation, please point me at the docs about how to access the stored application data (**from a non-mac-os platform**), I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I spend few minutes googling the problem and came up with this, which looks which looks interesting as alternatives. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-cloud-solutions-using-linux/ although it very evident that there a lot running on the flavour of linux you want to use.

Comment: Apple want you to use Apple and its one of their success/principle product ideas, they are the opposite of Microsoft who sell their sole to anyone who wants to build hardware for Windows. The more Apple work on making iCloud available to non-Apple platforms, the less profit for them, its in their interests to keep it Apple, so you buy more Apple and don't use linux/windows.

Comment: And a final word, as already hinted linux has many flavours these days, and you need to be more specific with your query naming the flavour your using I think to find a solution. Maybe you can find a forum for that flavour.

Comment: @user3069232 - I'm trying to access the data from an application **I didn't write**. Sure, there are lots of options, but I can't exactly modify the application someone else wrote. **I can't change the choice of cloud storage here**.

Comment: Its not ideal, but wait can't you access this data via the web with your python script and parse that? I know its not ideal? But possible no?

Comment: @user3069232 - Can you access application data via the web? I can't seem to do so via icloud.com